# iOS - Implicit coercion to 32 bits in the database is not recommended

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsinteger

All,

Please help, I think I am going mad, but I have an existing app which is designed for 32bit standard device. However, when I run on 64bit it's having problems, I am getting the following:

```
CoreData: warning: Property 'jobId' is a 64 bit scalar type on class 'JobSummary' 
that does not match its entity's property's 32 bit scalar type.  
Implicit coercion to 32 bits in the database is not recommended.
```

`jobId` is `NSInteger`

**Is their something I need to do for it to work in both? Currently it's one or the other.**

Comment: The problem is that `int`, `NSNumber`, et al, are whatever they want to be.  They change from platform to platform and are effectively non-portable.

Comment: NSNumber should be portable, unlike the primitives.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift you can use something like this:

```
@NSManaged var jobId: Int32
```

It works fine on both 32bit and 64bits devices.

Answer (score 1):

If it is feasible, transform your scalar values to objects, i.e. `NSNumber`. In the new model version, make sure you `int` types are what you need (making them bigger in case you are not sure).